# Why default route is required to access inbound ports

Tags: port-forwarding, tcpip

I have this network configuration:

```
- Local router 10.0.0.1, public IP 1.2.3.4
  forwarding port 1002 to 10.0.0.2
  forwarding port 1003 to 10.0.0.3
- Local host 10.0.0.2, server on port 1002, no default route
- Local host 10.0.0.3, server on port 1003, default route via 10.0.0.1
- Remote host public IP 5.6.7.8
```

No firewalls are configured.

I can connect from 10.0.0.3 to 10.0.0.2:1002 without issues.

From 5.6.7.8 I connect to 1.2.3.4:1003 without issue, but 1.2.3.4:1002 doesn't respond. However, if I add a default route via 10.0.0.1 on host 10.0.0.2, connection starts working.

So connection to a 10.0.0.2:1002 always works on local network, but works from remote hosts only when default route is enabled.

I don't understand the difference: from 10.0.0.2 perspective, why and inbound packed is different when coming from another local IP or when it is being forwarded?

Comment: Where have you added the default route?

Comment: Doesn't 10.0.0.2 need to know how to send packets back to 5.6.7.8? It'd need to know a default route. Does 10.0.0.3 have a default route set? I'd imagine it would have to.

Comment: @djsmiley2k: it's written in the question: _add a default route via 10.0.0.1 on host 10.0.0.2_

Comment: @DawnBenton: but how does 10.0.0.2 know how to send packets back to 10.0.0.3? Why it is different? That's the point of the question. Yes, 10.0.0.3 has the default route set, that's written in the question.

Comment: 10.0.0.2 doesn't need to route to 10.0.0.3 because it can see it. The 'default roure' is how packets get sent to another network. 2 and 3 are on the same network. Also, I apologize I didn't scroll far enough to see that you had specified that 3 had a route set.

Comment: @DawnBenton: but forwarded packages aren't coming from 10.0.0.1? 10.0.0.2 can see it... - Why don't you write a full explanatory answer instead of comments?

Answer (score 1):

When 10.0.0.2 receives the request from 5.6.7.8 and tries to respond, if it doesn't have an explicit route to 5.6.7.8 or a default route to fall back on, it will not know where to send the response.

Explanation:
Assuming 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3 are on the same subnet (determined by the subnet mask)

An example route table on 10.0.0.2 (ROUTE PRINT in Windows)

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        10.0.0.2
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.0.2
(added by me)10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0         10.0.0.99       10.0.0.2
```

From 10.0.0.2, the .3 machine is within the network destination of "10.0.0.0". This is "On-Link", meaning 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3 are on the same logical link. Thus, packets to and from .2 and .3 do not need to be routed. They send them directly to each other. No routing is involved.

When .3 or .2 try to send a packet back to 5.6.7.8 in response to a request from 5.6.7.8 (whether it's NAT forwarded or actually routed), because 5.6.7.8 is neither directly on-link nor within the other routes in the route table, it falls under the Network destination of "0.0.0.0" and would need to know where to send the packet for routing to the final destination -- in this case, the default route.

In the route table above, if 10.0.0.2 were trying to send to 10.0.2.50, it would route the packet via another router at 10.0.0.99 because that route is specified in the route table. If that route was not specified, it would fall back to the default route.

So, if there are no explicitly defined routes to a destination, and the destination is not on the local subnet, it gets sent to the default router.

Comment: So packets coming from `5.6.7.8` are simply routed when port forwarding is enabled? In other words, in the IP header `source` is `5.6.7.8` and `destination` is `1.2.3.4`, and `1.2.3.4` forwards it as-is to `10.0.0.2` without translating addresses?

Comment: If you don't have NAT setup then yes, it'll just forward it.

Comment: NAT rewrites the destination on the incoming packet header in order to deliver it to the host on the local network, but the source is not changed. So if 5.6.7.8 sends a request to 1.2.3.4:1002, then 10.0.0.2 will see a packet from 5.6.7.8 and try to respond to same. Note that the source of inbound packet is the same whether the internal destination is behind NAT or if it has a real routable IP address (say 1.2.3.6). All NAT does is make the outside see one host, rewrite the destination of inbound packets, and keep track with a port mapping table.